# ApplicationInsights high memory usage

Tags: azure-web-app-service, heap-memory, azure-application-insights, azure-webapps, appinsights

I am hosting a .NET 4.6.1 MVC app in a web app in Azure and collecting telemetry data using Application Insights. Over time memory usage of the app increases to a point where service degrades and a restart is required.

I am currently using version 2.22.0 of ApplicationInsights and the collection of this data is automatic configured by ApplicationInsights.config

I have taken snapshots of the heap memory usage while debugging in visual studio and can see that the memory increase is being caused by:

- String (The hierarchy of this looks like it includes the below 2)
- ConcurrentDictionary+Node<String, Boolean>
- ConcurrentDictionary+Node<String, Boolean>[]

[Memory usage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpU5p.png)

[Memory usage 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfpYR.png)

[String memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCDCl.png)

[Concurrent dictionary usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFCGp.png)

I'm out my depth here and not sure how to solve this problem?

I've noticed that a change to concurrent dictionary was made [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/pull/1211) but not sure if this is related?

Comment: Can you please share your code ?